# None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' in builder.RegisterType<ContentItemMetadataProvider>

Tags: autofac, kentico-mvc

Detailed error is as below

None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'KMVC12.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'KMVC12.Repositories.IPromotedContentRepository repository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(KMVC12.Repositories.IPromotedContentRepository, KMVC12.Repositories.IHomeRepository, KMVC12.Infrastructure.IOutputCacheDependencies)'.

Have removed set .PreserveExistingDefaults() in the builder.RegisterType which is i found it in one solution

I have below code in DependencyResolverConfig.cs file is this cause of the error?

```
 builder.RegisterType<ContentItemMetadataProvider>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .SingleInstance()
```

Unable to run the home page because of the above exception
Need to run it without any exception in the front end.

Comment: Does `ContentItemMetadataProvider` implements `IPromotedContentRepository` ?

Comment: This has been done removed declaration of IPromotedContentRepository from HomeCotroller which is unused to the controller

@CyrilDurand thanks for the response